# Does "payers" mean "insurance companies" or "individuals" in this context?

Tags: meaning-in-context

On the other hand, total healthcare spending in the US is growing at the slowest pace in decades, according to the Kaiser Family Foundation. Also, the shift to high-deductible plans has made insurance cheaper for employers, while recent changes to provider reimbursement have dragged down cost increases for private **payers**.

source: [www.businessinsider.com](http://www.businessinsider.com/FEDeral-reserve-inflation-PCE-CPI-healthcare-obamacare-epipen-problem-2016-9?IR=T)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"A private payer is a private insurance company. There are many private insurance companies in the U.S. Each company offers different types of plans that must meet or exceed basic standards set by the state and federal government."

Source: [Patient Navigator Training Collaborative](http://www.patientnavigatortraining.org/healthcare_system/module2/3_healthinsurancepayersplans.htm)